# backtrace not giving me complete stack trace

Tags: c++, c, xcode, macos, wxwidgets

I'm forcing a crash in my wxWidgets application (`MyApp`) in OSX, by doing the following in an event handler:

```
void MainFrame::buggyFunc( wxCommandEvent &event ) {
  int* a = NULL;
  *a = 1;
```

This generates the following stack trace:

```
0   MyApp                           0x000000010dc5d5d5 generateCrashLog(int)                    + 325
1   MyApp                           0x000000010dc5db46 abortHandler(int)                        + 118
2   libsystem_platform.dylib        0x00007fff94e6ceaa _sigtramp                             () + 26
3   ???                             0x00000000ffffffff 0x0 + 4294967295
4   MyApp                           0x0000000108a5880b wxAppConsoleBase::HandleEvent(wxEvtHandler*, void (wxEvtHandler::*)(wxEvent&), wxEvent&) const + 139
5   MyApp                           0x0000000108a588b7 wxAppConsoleBase::CallEventHandler(wxEvtHandler*, wxEventFunctor&, wxEvent&) const + 151
6   MyApp                           0x0000000108ba96e7 wxEvtHandler::ProcessEventIfMatchesId(wxEventTableEntryBase const&, wxEvtHandler*, wxEvent&) + 231
7   MyApp                           0x0000000108ba94c3 wxEventHashTable::HandleEvent(wxEvent&, wxEvtHandler*) + 243
8   MyApp                           0x0000000108bab276 wxEvtHandler::TryHereOnly(wxEvent&)      + 134
9   MyApp                           0x0000000108bac71d wxEvtHandler::TryBeforeAndHere(wxEvent&) + 77
10  MyApp                           0x0000000108bab03f wxEvtHandler::ProcessEventLocally(wxEvent&) + 47
11  MyApp                           0x0000000108baafb0 wxEvtHandler::ProcessEvent(wxEvent&)     + 336
12  MyApp                           0x0000000108a270df wxWindowBase::TryAfter(wxEvent&)         + 175
13  MyApp                           0x0000000108baafe6 wxEvtHandler::ProcessEvent(wxEvent&)     + 390
14  MyApp                           0x0000000108bab4a0 wxEvtHandler::SafelyProcessEvent(wxEvent&) + 32
15  MyApp                           0x0000000108a1e4e5 wxWindowBase::HandleWindowEvent(wxEvent&) const + 37
16  MyApp                           0x00000001089c8d8b wxMenuBase::SendEvent(int, int)          + 443
17  MyApp                           0x000000010885630a wxMenu::HandleCommandProcess(wxMenuItem*, wxWindow*) + 314
18  MyApp                           0x00000001088d8b6b -[wxNSMenuItem clickedAction:] + 107
19  libsystem_trace.dylib           0x00007fff9052107a _os_activity_initiate

and so on...
```

**Question 1:**
Why isn't `buggyFunc` in the stack trace? It doesn't matter if I use `backtrace`, `libunwind` or `wxDebugReport/wxStackWalker` (as suggested by VZ). The resulting stack trace is always the same. The top-most function is never in the list. Now if `buggyFunc` were to call another function (let's say `buggyFunc2`), where the crash is forced, then `buggyFunc` will in fact be included, while `buggyFunc2` wont be. So why is the top-most function never present in the trace?

**Question 2: (SOLVED. See Answer Below)**
When I run `MyApp` in debug mode, it says `Caught signal 11`, which is a `SIGSEGV`, which is what I'd expect, but release mode gives 4, which is `SIGILL`. What's happening here?

**Answer:** Thanks to the suggestion by VZ, I looked in to Xcode build settings and found this:

[image]
Setting `Optimization level` to `None` solves this issue. But, now I've got another question...

**Question 3:**
When I build a `RelWithDebInfo` version of the application, I still get meaningful function names in the stack trace despite `Generate Debug Symbols` set to `No` for it. Why is this?

Answer (score 1):

I can't directly answer your first question, but if you're using wxWidgets anyhow, why don't you use [wxStackWalker](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.1.0/classwx_stack_walker.html) or even [wxDebugReport](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.1.0/classwx_debug_report.html) instead of reimplementing them?

As for the second one, you really need to look at the disassembly, it's quite likely that the optimizer replaces your code with something entirely different or even removes it entirely as it doesn't seem to have any side effects.

Edit: as for the third question (which should really be asked independently as it doesn't have much to do with the other ones), the function names are kept in the resulting binary even without debug information, you may use `strip` to get rid of them (although usually there should be no real reason to).

Comment: Thank you for that suggestion. I tried implementing `wxDebugReport` using the example provided, but I get a linker error. `Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "wxDebugReport::AddAll(wxDebugReport::Context)"`. Can't seem to find any info about this. Undefined usually means a missing object (or framework), but I thought this class was just part of wxWidgets.

Comment: Also, I tried using wxStackWalker, but I have the same issue as described in my question. `buggyFunc` is not in the list of frames walked by it. Possibly because wxStackWalker uses backtrace() internally.

Comment: `wxDebugReport` is in the "qa" library, make sure you link with it. If `wxStackWalker` doesn't work correctly neither and if you can reproduce it in a simple example, please open a bug on [wxTrac](http://trac.wxwidgets.org/) about it.

Comment: Thanks. I found the reason for 'Question 2' thanks to your suggestion about the optimizer (see edited question), but now I've got a new question (Question 3). `wxDebugReport` worked for me after linking to `qa`, although the issue of `buggyFunc` not being included in the stack trace still remains. However, I've noticed that it's the top-most function that is always excluded from the trace (see edit for Question 1).